# Android: Finding components dynamically

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I'm developing an app which includes a ListView. The ListView items includes, among others components, a button.

The point is that this ListView may vary over time and I'm not sure how I can get these buttons to develop their action (it is always the same action, just adapted to the list view item data).

Thanks for the help!!

PS: If someone is wondering, it is a map app. The list includes some interesting places and I want to show their specifics locations when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your list's adapter `Override` getView()

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, null);
            }


                Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view_id);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Do something when clicked
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Just what I need :D Thanks!